# MySQL query breaks when additional left join added

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, left-join

EDITED:

I found the problem. The column "base3_run_id" was being referenced in another line of the query, making it ambiguous. I was apparently mistaken when I said it ran fine in workbench; I thought that was the case, but then today it didn't work.  Consider this question solved, and the problem was my own... let's go with idiocy.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have a MySQL instance running on the free tier of Amazon's AWS RDS service, using it to supply data to a website running on an EC2 instance. I'm having trouble adding to a query I need to use, and I can't figure out why.

The PHP file (in the relevant parts, from what I can tell) looks like this:

```
$i_batting_leaders_sql="select 
    bat_name as batter,
    if(bat_home_id=0,away_team_name,home_team_name) as team,
    ...
    (e.sb+f.sb) as sb,
    (e.cs+f.cs) as cs,
    ...
    from papb_pbp a 
    left join papb_lwts b on ...
    left join papb_lwts c on ...
    left join (select ...
    left join (select year_id, base1_run_id, sum(if(run1_sb_fl='T',1,0)) as sb, sum(if(run1_cs_fl='T',1,0)) as cs from papb_pbp where year_id = 2015 group by base1_run_id) e on a.bat_name = e.base1_run_id
    left join (select year_id, base2_run_id, sum(if(run2_sb_fl='T',1,0)) as sb, sum(if(run2_cs_fl='T',1,0)) as cs from papb_pbp where year_id = 2015 group by base2_run_id) f on a.bat_name = f.base2_run_id
    where a.year_id = 2015 and b.year_id = 2015 and c.year_id = 2015 and d.year_id = 2015
    group by batter";
$result = $conn->query($i_batting_leaders_sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><th><a href=".$link_base."batter>Batter</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."team>Team</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."PA>PA</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."AB>AB</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."H>H</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."1B>1B</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."2B>2B</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."3B>3B</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."HR>HR</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."K>K</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."BB>BB</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."iBB>iBB</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."HBP>HBP</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."p_per_pa>Pitch/PA</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."SB>SB</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."CS>CS</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."sac>Sac</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."DP>DP</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."runners_per_PA>Runners/PA</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."run3_score>Run3B-score%</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."AVG>AVG</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."OBP>OBP</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."SLG>SLG</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."ISO>ISO</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."BABIP>BABIP</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."k_pct>K%</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."bb_pct>BB%</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."wOBA>wOBA</a></th><th><a href=".$link_base."wRC>wRC</a></th></tr>";

// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "<tr><td><a href=\"http://****/player.php?name=".$row["batter"]."\">".$row["batter"]."</td><td>".$row["team"]."</td><td>".$row["PA"]."</td><td>".$row["AB"]."</td><td>".$row["H"]."</td><td>".$row["1B"]."</td><td>".$row["2B"]."</td><td>".$row["3B"]."</td><td>".$row["HR"]."</td><td>".$row["K"]."</td><td>".$row["BB"]."</td><td>".$row["iBB"]."</td><td>".$row["HBP"]."</td><td>".$row["p_per_pa"]."</td><td>".$row["SB"]."</td><td>".$row["CS"]."</td><td>".$row["sac"]."</td><td>".$row["DP"]."</td><td>".$row["runners_per_PA"]."</td><td>".$row["run3_score"]."</td><td>".$row["AVG"]."</td><td>".$row["OBP"]."</td><td>".$row["SLG"]."</td><td>".$row["ISO"]."</td><td>".$row["BABIP"]."</td><td>".$row["k_pct"]."</td><td>".$row["bb_pct"]."</td><td>".$row["wOBA"]."</td><td>".$row["wRC"]."</td></tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

This works fine, and produces the correct and expected results.  However, when I try to change it to

```
(e.sb+f.sb+g.sb) as sb,
(e.cs+f.cs+g.cs) as cs,
```

and add another join after the join to f but before the where clause:

```
left join (select year_id,
base3_run_id, sum(if(run3_sb_fl='T',1,0)) as sb,
sum(if(run3_cs_fl='T',1,0)) as cs
from papb_pbp where year_id = 2015
group by base3_run_id) g
on a.bat_name = g.base3_run_id
```

The PHP result is "0 results".  It runs fine in workbench, just not via PHP. The behavior occurs when the join is added, regardless of if I select from the joined table. I can't for the life of me figure out what could be going wrong here.  Can anyone help?  Also, I'd be happy to post more information as needed.

Thanks,
John